# Ansible list a directories files (ansible 2.9.10)

Tags: ansible

So I was recently frustrated by how hard it is to do the a simple find and change permissions on a list of files using Ansible. I achieved it two ways, both work, but I want to know if someone has a better method.

My first method, I just ask Ansible to do the same as I would do in bash, like so:

```yaml
tasks:
- shell: ls -1 "{{ SomeDir }}"
  register: file_names
- command: chmod 754 "{{ SomeDir }}/{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ file_names.stdout_lines }}"
```

I came back to it today to try and find a more Ansible native way of doing the task and came up with this, but it just seems so clunky for such a simple task:

```yaml
tasks:
- name: "Find all files in the directory"
  find:
    paths: "{{ SomeDir }}"
    file_type: file
  register : find_output

- name: "loop through the .files output and then pick out the .path attribute"
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    mode: '0754'
  loop:
    "{{ find_output.files }}"
```

I'm not great at output manipulation, as you can see. I would have loved it if I could have done something like `{{ find_output.files.path }}`, but I could not get lookups or flatten operations to work, maybe someone can set me straight.

Comment: What is the goal of the fact `filepath_list`? Why don't you just go: `path: "{{ item.path }}"` while looping `loop: "{{ find_output.files }}"` in the permission task right away?

Comment: I tried that and got a bunch of errors, let me give it another go though, maybe I made a typo.

Comment: GDI , yep was a typo , sent me off down a goose chase ... i'll amend my question above, would be nice to know still if there is a better way to pull out attributes two layers down, eg find_output.files.path

Comment: Mhm, your question does make much sense anymore. The `file` module acts on one and only file. So you cannot go `{{ find_output.files.path }}`, or at least you cannot do that on the `file` module without the loop.

Comment: yep you are right it, I was just wishing that I could pull out file paths this way, that is all.
Question still stands from an efficiency point of view, can it be done more easily than the above methods?

Comment: It can be done other ways, it can even indeed be done with converting the list of dictionary in a simply list of string containing the files path. Now, would those be better version of your actual playbook? I would definitely say no, because this would involve data modification for no real purpose.

Comment: Actually, there is a simpler way if I understand your requirements properly, it is using `with_fileglob` added this to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea for you to simplify it, since, if I understand it properly, you are just looking to change all the files permissions in a folder, non-recursively.
To achieve this, you could also use the [`fileglob`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/fileglob.html) lookup and its equivalent `with_fileglob` structure.

Effectively reducing your two tasks in one:

```yaml
- file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    mode: "0754"
  with_fileglob: "{{ SomeDir }}/*"
```

---

If you want to make a simple list out of a complex list of dictionaries like the `file` module is yielding you, you can use a combination of the [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map) and [`list`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list) filters.

Here is an example playbook achieving this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ faked_find_output.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
      vars:
        faked_find_output:
          changed: false
          failed: false
          files:
            - gid: 0
              uid: 0
              path: /path/to/file1
              size: 0
            - gid: 0
              uid: 0
              path: /path/to/file2
              size: 0
```

This yields:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "/path/to/file1",
        "/path/to/file2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

**But mind that**, this will not work with your use case, as the `file` module does not accept a list of [`path`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-path).

So in you case, the best you can do with this is:

```yaml
- file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    mode: "0754"
  loop: "{{ find_output.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
```

But, to be honest, this is just throwing complexity in for no reason.

Comment: Thanks for the loop line, this is the sort of filter I want to get better at and this is a really nice working example for me.

Comment: `fileglob` operates against files on the control host, not files on the target host.